# Get details of card on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of cards of my website and all the cards contain a submit button. I want that when the submit button is clicked, I can get the details of the cards such as the status of the switch and the name of the equipment on that particular card. How do I achieve this?

Below is how my cards look like. Let us assume that I put a button on each of the cards, then I want this to happen on the click of that button.

[image: Above mentioned image]

This is the structure of my card, but I have no idea as to how to achieve the above said thing, due to which I haven't been able to begin with anything

```
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col s12 m6"> 
       <div class="card"> 
         <div class="card-content white-text"> 
           <span class="card-title">Air Conditioner</span> 
         </div> 
         <div class="card-action" id="action"> 
            <div id="status">ON</div> 
              <div class="switch"> 
                 <label> on <input type="checkbox"> <span class="lever"></span> off </label> 
              </div>
             </div> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
   </div>
```

I would be obliged to receive a swift response from the community! :D

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yourself yet? If so, post it, else this question is too broad.

Comment: This is the structure of my card, but I have no idea as to how to achieve the above said thing, due to which I haven't been able to begin with anything @CertainPerformance

Comment: Use a [constuctor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: @PHPglue Could you please elaborate with a bit of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

You haven't provided much info or shown any code that you're using, so I'm going to provide a general answer and assume you're using jQuery.

So, say you have a card like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox">

    <button id="button-1">Get value</button>
</div>
```

You could use jQuery to get the value:

```
// Wait for jQuery to load,
$(document).ready(function() {
    // when #button-1 is clicked,
    $("#button-1").click(function () {
        // save the value of #checkbox-1 as a variable,
        var myValue = $("#checkbox-1").is(':checked');
        // and test it to confirm it worked.
        console.log(myValue);
    });
});
```